# Não repetir dados retornados Mysqli

Tags: php, array, mysqli

Tenho este código que me trás os meses cadastrados no banco. Más como possui varias linhas, quero retornar apenas uma vez cada valor.

```
// Fazendo a conexão
    $conexao  = mysqli_connect($this->dbservidor,$this->dbusuario,$this->dbsenha) or die (mysqli_connect_error($conexao));
    $select   = mysqli_select_db($conexao,$this->dbnome) or die (mysqli_connect_error($select));    
    $query    = mysqli_query($conexao, " SELECT mes FROM programacaoclientes WHERE idCliente = '$idCliente' ");
    $array    = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    $nums     = mysqli_num_rows($query);

//
    if ( $nums > 0 )
    {   
        // percorrendo
            do
            {   
                // pegando as datas
                    $mes = $array['mes'];

                //
                    echo "<p> <a href='a.php'>$mes</a> </p>";

            }while( $array = mysqli_fetch_array($query) );

    }

Sáida:
  Julho
  Julho
  Julho
  Agosto
  Agosto
```

eu queria retornar apenas uma vez, sem repitir... Qual e metodologia devo usar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apenas coloque um `GROUP BY` no seu`SELECT`:

```
// Fazendo a conexão
    $conexao  = mysqli_connect($this->dbservidor,$this->dbusuario,$this->dbsenha) or die (mysqli_connect_error($conexao));
    $select   = mysqli_select_db($conexao,$this->dbnome) or die (mysqli_connect_error($select));    
    $query    = mysqli_query($conexao, " SELECT mes FROM programacaoclientes WHERE idCliente = '$idCliente' GROUP BY mes");
    $array    = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    $nums     = mysqli_num_rows($query);

//
    if ( $nums > 0 )
    {   
        // percorrendo
            do
            {   
                // pegando as datas
                    $mes = $array['mes'];

                //
                    echo "<p> <a href='a.php'>$mes</a> </p>";

            }while( $array = mysqli_fetch_array($query) );

    }
```

Comment: Perfeito, Roberto uma dúvida.. Oque exatamente o GROUP BY  faz?

Comment: Ele agrupa os resultados por um ou mais campos, no caso colocamos `GROUP BY mes`, então a mysql vai agrupar todos os resultados que tiver o campo `mes` igual.

Comment: Creio que o `DISTINCT` neste caso seria mais apropriado. Exemplo: `$query    = mysqli_query($conexao, " SELECT DISTINCT mes FROM programacaoclientes WHERE idCliente = '$idCliente' ");`